# Problem with solely year by year prediction using FBProphet

Tags: python, pandas, forecasting, facebook-prophet

I have a set of yearly cumulative data. Particularly, it is the number of deaths per year for the last half of a century in one region. The problem is that I do not know how to set up the FBProphet to make a forecast on a yearly basis. For example, I have data like this (the number of deaths is the second column)

```
ds y

1950-01-01 1000

1951-01-01 1010

1952-01-01 1005

...  ...

2009-01-01 2101

2010-01-01 2038
```

Assume that the pandas data frame is assigned to a variable `mortality`. Next, in order to simplify my problem, I take that the data is increasing linearly and I want a forecast for the next 10 years. Now, I am following the book, so to speak (I am using Python).

```
model = Prophet(growth="linear")

model.fit(mortality)

periods = 10

future = model.make_future_dataframe(periods=periods)

future_data = model.predict(future)
```

The issue is that I get the forecast for the next ten days: from 2010-01-02 to 2010-01-11. I do not know how to tell FBProphet to ignore dates, i.e., only to focus on years. As far as I know, under `'ds'` column dates must be in format YYYY-MM-DD.

One solution, but a really bad one is to make a forecast for 10 * 365 days, and then to extract the dates on Jan 1st. But that is really cumbersome. It takes really a lot of time and sucks a lot of memory. Furthermore, if the growth is logistic, or there are some special things to take into account, I think this approach will not work. The other solution is to transform yearly data into daily data, i.e., for some 60 consecutive days, without any seasonality to consider. Then, to make a forecast, and again to transform the result back into appropriate form. But this is also cumbersome and what if there is some seasonality? What if there is a rise and fall every ten years? I hope you understand what is the issue.

Comment: I have stumbled upon this in Prophet source code:

 ```def make_future_dataframe(self, periods, freq='D', include_history=True):
        freq: Any valid frequency for pd.date_range, such as 'D' or 'M'.```

Have you tried using freq parameter and 'Y' as argument?

Comment: @VladimirGromes Thanks. It seems that, for some strange reason, the valid frequency argument  is not 'Y', but 'A', when it comes to years. It has something to do with acceptable parameter aliases in pandas. If you want, you can write your comment as an answer (just with different parameter alias), so that I can accept it. :)